# Visual SQL Builder that includes ability to update data

Tags: mysql, wysiwyg

I do not know SQL and need to create a script that will update data in our database. I know there is software and services out there that provide a drag & drop interface that build sql queries to export data and build charts, but are there any that also enable someone with zero knowledge of SQL to create a SQL query that I can copy and paste into phpMyAdmin that will UPDATE data? My database is MySQL. Thanks in advance for any recommendations.

Comment: You don't need a tool, you need a quick introduction to SQL. Using any kind of relational DB engine without any SQL knowledge is a big no-no. Then you can look after tools.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives to MS-Access (per @knb) that have decent-to-good visual query builders and that will connect to multiple DBMSs are Navicat, FlySpeed SQL, LibreOffice Base, and Toad.  However, with all of these, as with Access, you will need to convert a SELECT query to an INSERT or UPDATE query yourself.  @Alejando provides the best recommendation: learn SQL, and then you have much more power to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, if you have MS Office available, you can connect with MS Access and an ODBC data source to mySQL. Access has a Visual Query Builder Frontend where you can build a SELECT query by dragging and dropping the column-names you need, from a panel into a grid.

Wit an appropriate  menu selection then you can **transform** the SELECT ... WHERE query to an UPDATE ... SET ... WHERE query and view/generate the corresponding SQL code. But the expressivity is limited.

I don't know if the more modern MS SQL Server Data tools have a similar feature. I only know it from Access, where I've used this many years ago.

Comment: Maybe too technical? To how to know when to `UPDATE` and when to `INSERT` is obvious to you & me, but maybe not to everyone?

Comment: It is indeed technical. But my solution *is* a simple GUI based solution to generate UPDATE queries. I've used it a few times myself to escape quote-characters in the WHERE clause, for instance. - Maybe she can discuss my answer with people  who know what I mean. And it is not unrealistic to assume that she has MS Office available in a corporate environment.

Comment: I agree, and this might well be the answer. Although there is a difference between Office & Office Pro. Without Pro, there is no MS Access.